# I just updated to Awesomium 1.7.5.1 and none of my existing VB projects using Awesomium will work. Any advice?

Tags: .net, vb.net, awesomium

I just updated to Awesomium 1.7.5.1 and none of my existing VB projects using Awesomium will work.  Specifically, it appears that the designer is not recognizing any of the Awesomium web components which I dragged into my form prior to the upgrade.  I've just lost a lot of work here.  If anybody has a workaround for this problem, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post at least some errors you got?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the properties section of the ide for the assemblies of the controls that you're using. Specifically check to see that the 'Specific Version' property is set to false.  Do this for all of the affected assemblies.  If you're lucky that will be the problem.

Comment: How do I get to the Specific Version property?  I'm running Visual Studio 13

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I figured it out.  I had to go into the Designer and comment out all Awesomium controls because those referred to the old version of Awesomium.  I then dragged and dropped into the designer window replacements for the controls I had removed.  After I had reset their properties to match the properties of the old controls, everything worked fine.  I tried to find the "Specific Version" property referred to in the email above, but I couldn't for the life of me.  Thanks to all who considered the question.